# What is the fundamental group of a cone?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups

I am reading an article on orbifolds and it describes the cone as the quotient of unit 2-dim. disc by a finite cyclic group of rotations. But how is it's fundamental group finite cyclic?

Comment: The fundamental group should be trivial. Can you say which article you are reading? Also what is the finite cyclic group exactly and how does it act on the disc?

Comment: What you're reading is talking about the orbifold fundamental group, not the fundamental group of the underlying topological space. That this fundamental group is $\Bbb Z/n$ should follow essentially immediately after defining the orbifold fundamental group.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, ... thanks @MikeMiller